# Server cuts array post data

Tags: php, apache, php-ini

I have a form with values like `bars[4]`. So I have about 1480 items. When I press submit and check post data the array contains exactly 1000 items. What the settings do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[max_input_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars)

defaults to 1000, just as you're finding.